# Google Picker API for sharing documents

Tags: google-drive-api, google-picker

I have implemented the Picker API for my Web App and there is only one inconvenient.

The App permit a user to open a project and share all kind of documents. One of the methods available to share documents with others is throughout Google Drive, so the User select the documents within its account and the App show the links to download the content shared.

All works fine but the issue is related with permissions. If other users click on any link, it indicates that he needs permission from the owner, so he must wait until access is granted.

Is there any way to avoid this? I mean, the owner share the files knowing it can be downloaded by any other user from the website.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does your application prompt the user for Drive permissions to get an OAuth token? without this your application can't modify the permissions on the user's documents

Comment: Well, I have a button in my site and when the user click on it a dialog box come up (from Google Drive) for the user to grant access the App, so once accepted, a new dialog box come up with the files. When the user selects the desired files, the App, get the links generated by Google Drive and published in the Site.

Comment: You might need to add this scope 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive' to your list of scopes, this will allow you to invoke the Permissions API (https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions) to set the permission on the individual files. Some users might not be happy to allow this